# Android: Await result of CallBack with Kotlin Coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, algolia

I am gradually transitioning from RXJava to Coroutines in my current project. I have a situation where I need to halt execution and wait for the result returned by my callback. I have converted my RXJava method to use coroutines in the following way :

```
   suspend fun fetchProducts(ids: List<String>) = suspendCoroutine<List<ProductItem>> { continuation ->
    val getProducts = repo.search(ids, null, null)
    getProducts.subscribe(
        { callResult ->
            productRequestInProgress.postValue(false)
            continuation.resume(callResult.result())
        },
        { error ->
            productRequestInProgress.postValue(false)
            //continuation.resumeWithException(t)
        }
    )

}
```

I am calling the **fetchProducts** method from a .mapByPage function but I am getting the message *"Suspend function 'await' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function"* . Any ideas on how I can correctly call the **fetchProducts** function and wait for the results in the mapByPage function? This is where the I am getting the error message. Thanks

```
val dataSourceFactory = SearcherSingleIndexDataSource.Factory(searcher) { hit ->
    Product(hit.json.getValue("id").jsonPrimitive.content)
}.mapByPage { it ->
    viewModelScope.launch {
       fetchProducts(it.mapNotNull { it.id })
    }.await()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap the coroutine in a [runBlocking](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-blocking.html) block.

> Runs a new coroutine and blocks the current thread interruptibly until
> its completion.
> ...
> It is designed to bridge regular blocking code to
> libraries that are written in suspending style

```
.mapByPage { it ->
    runBlocking {
           fetchProducts(it.mapNotNull { it.id })
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if you need the extra `launch` function. You should also be able to pass the required information to the runBlocking function and use async { }.await() directly in it.

Comment: Just to add ( and for anyone else who stumbles upon this), you are right no need to use the extra launch function. I will edit the answer

Answer (score 1):

yes `await()` is defined as a suspend function , suspend keyword is like a signal that this function is a long running task and hence should run asynchronously given that `await()` is a suspend function if we were allowed to execute it without a couroutine or another suspend function that would mean we are making a blocking call with that wrong running task , hence we are not allowed to do that.

so suspend function can be called from coroutine or another suspend function this rule is guarantee that the long running task which is inside the suspend function doesn't block the main thread.

also you are using launch you should use `async` function instead of `launch` launch is for fire and forget work and `async` is used when you want a result back after completion.

generally if your suspend function has a return type use `async` use launch otherwise

as you want a `List` of product back you use async as follows.

```
viewModelScope.launch{
val products = viewModelScope.async(Dispathers.Default) { // Dispathers.Default is used for CPU intensive work, even if you don't pass anything Dispathers.Default is there , use Dispacther.IO for IO , Dispathers.Main for working with views in coroutine , like updating text view
   fetchProducts(it.mapNotNull { it.id })
}.await()
}
```